# "Proof" of chain rule

Tags: calculus

I wanted a midly rigorous proof to make the chain rule more intuitive to me, and this is what I found: http://web.mit.edu/wwmath/calculus/differentiation/chain-proof.html

However, I am not sure how how going from step two to three on this part of the proof is justified: http://web.mit.edu/wwmath/calculus/differentiation/chaineq/chaineq31.gif

High school sophomore in calc ab

Thanks for any help!! ☺

Comment: the use of infinitesimal is blurring  and ambiguous

Comment: I know that, but if infinitesimals weren't being used, how would going from step 2 to 3 be justified?

Comment: take a glimpse at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Proofs

Comment: @janmarqz: This proof does not use infinitesimals.

Comment: what is *this* you mention? @ParamanandSingh

Comment: @janmarqz: "this" refers to "The proof linked in the question".

Comment: [Caratheodory's formulation](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Real_Analysis/Differentiation) is a useful trick to establish a rigorous proof without losing too much of the intuition.

Answer (score 2):

The proof given in your link is wrong, but in a very subtle way. The main problem with the proof is that there may be cases where $\Delta u = 0$ identically when $\Delta x \to 0$. And then you can't do division and multiplication by $\Delta u$. This case however is possible only when $du/dx = 0$ and further it is easy to show that $dy/dx = 0$ in this case so that the chain rule $dy/dx = dy/du \times du/dx$ remains valid here. Apart from this small gap, the proof in your link is OK.

Comment: There are also cases where $\Delta u = 0$ along a sequence of values of $\Delta x$ going to zero.  So you still cannot multiply and divide by $\Delta u$.

Comment: @GEdgar: I meant to include this case also, but perhaps the language was not explicit/clear enough. The derivative $du/dx$ is $0$ in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an intuitive quasi-proof:

---

Let $\frac{dF(x)}{dx}=f(x)$ and $g=g(x)$

$$\frac{dF(g)}{dx}=\frac{dF(g)}{dx}\frac{dg}{dg}=\frac{dF(g)}{dg}\frac{dg}{dx}=f(g)g'(x)$$

Since $\frac{dF(g)}{dg}=f(g)$ and $\frac{dg}{dx}=g'(x)$

---

If one does not feel justified, we can use the following:

$$\frac{F(g(x))-F(g(h))}{x-h}=\frac{F(g(x))-F(g(h))}{x-h}\frac{g(x)-g(h)}{g(x)-g(h)}=\frac{F(g(x))-F(g(h))}{g(x)-g(h)}\frac{g(x)-g(h)}{x-h}$$

So we have

$$\frac{dF(g)}{dx}=\lim_{h\to x}\frac{F(g(x))-F(g(h))}{x-h}=\lim_{h\to x}\frac{F(g(x))-F(g(h))}{g(x)-g(h)}\frac{g(x)-g(h)}{x-h}\\=f(g)g'(x)$$

Comment: this is clearly the worst thing to say. If you want an intuitive proof, use instead $F(x) = ax+b, g(x) = cx+d$, and make it rigorous by adding the $o(x)$ terms

Comment: @user1952009 It is not.  It is the given [Chain rule proof via infinitesimals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Proof_via_infinitesimals) written using Leibniz notation.

Comment: Yeah sure, define the hyperreal numbers for proving something trivial

Comment: @user1952009 Or we can use limit definitions of the derivative, but the message is the same.  (and I agree seemingly trivial things are too complicated.)

Comment: Or, you can use that $f'(a) = \alpha \Leftrightarrow f(a+h) = f(a)+ \alpha h+o(h)$ as $h\to 0$, which is useful, intuitive, and makes all the derivatives formulas trivial.

Comment: @user1952009 Then sure, post that as an answer.  My answer is just more directed at the specific question at hand.